# jquery gmap3 - calculate center point and zoom of multiple dynamically generated marker co-ordinates - google maps api 3

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I am basically trying to some how set an auto-zoom and auto-center function for my `#map_div` div. But because my markers are dynamically generated, I somehow need the zoom and center to work automatically, based on the width and height of my `#map_div`

But as you can see in my gmap3 script that I am having to determin the zoom and center manually, not cool.

I found this script snippet below, but cant see how to intergrate it with my `.gmap3` script. Is it possible to integrate it somehow with my `.gmap3` jquery plugin script?

Center point calculation var...

```
// map: an instance of google.maps.Map object
// latlng: an array of google.maps.LatLng objects
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( );
for ( var i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++ ) {
  latlngbounds.extend( latlng[ i ] );
}
map.fitBounds( latlngbounds );
```

[Found the above script here](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/zoom-to-fit-all-markers-on-google-map.html)

My `.gmap3` script below...

```
jQuery(function($) {    

    $('#map_div').gmap3({
        action: 'init',
        options: {
            center: [50.799019, -1.132037],
            zoom: 5,
            scrollwheel: false
        }
    }, {
        action: 'addMarkers',
        markers: [{
            lat: 50.799019,
            lng: -1.132037,
            data: 'Test One'},
        {
            lat: 50.365162,
            lng: -4.712017,
            data: 'Test Two'},
        {
            lat: 54.518726,
            lng: -5.881054,
            data: 'Test Three'},
        {
            lat: 52.780964,
            lng: -1.211863,
            data: 'Test Four'},
        {
            lat: 51.433998,
            lng: -2.549690,
            data: 'Test Five'
        }],
        marker: {
            options: {
                draggable: false
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I would normally do a jsfiddle but the site is down.

Any help with this would be so great thanks.

Comment: hi Joshc, did you find the way to make it work with gmap3? would you mind to share it? tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try the **autofit** feature?

http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/16-misc/autofit-58

> This function extends map bounds to contain each overlay added
>   (markers, circle ...)

```
$('#test').gmap3(
  { circle:{
      options: {
        center: [37.772323, -122.214897],
        radius : 2500000,
        fillColor : "#008BB2",
        strokeColor : "#005BB7"
      }
    }
  },
  "autofit"
);
```

Comment: It doesn't adjust the zoom level. From docs: "This function is not and auto-zoom".

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, you can access the coordinates of the markers in the callback of "marker", and use them then to center the map and autozoom it with fitBounds:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap3({
map: {
  options: {
    zoom: 9,
    center: [view.lat, view.lng]
  },
   marker : {
      values : markersArray,
      options : {
        draggable : false
      },
  callback:function(m)
     { //m will be the array of markers
       var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       for(var i=0;i<m.length;++i)
       {
         bounds.extend(m[i].getPosition());
       }
       try{
            var map=$(this).gmap3('get');
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter())
           }catch(e){}
     }
  }
 }
});
```